# Examples of problems in second order arithmetic that can only be solved in third order arithmetic

Tags: logic, computability, higher-order-logic

So I was reading about Goodstein Sequences:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem

where it is given as an example of a theorem that is not decidable in PA but decidable in second order arithmetic.

So now my question, can one generate a 2-dimensional list of theorems $X_{i,j}$ where $X_{i,j}$ can be stated in $i^{th}$ order arithmetic, but whose proof requires $j^{th}$ order arithmetic?

Getting something where the separation between $i$ and $j$ is greater than 1 seems to be very hard.

### Ideas for $X_{2,3}$

So in the same vein as the Goodstein sequences we can define "minimal-hereditary-hyperoperator-form" of a natural number $X$ with respect to a base $b$.

Before we do this we introduce hyperoperator-forms:

Observe that $X$ has a unique base $b$ representation of the form

$$ a_0 b^0 + a_1 b^1 + ... a_kb^k  $$

where $0 < a_i < b$, but now suppose the $k$ were very large. We can compress these expressions further by using tetration:

$$ a_0 b^0 + a_1 b^1 + ... a_k(b\uparrow \uparrow c)\uparrow d   $$

And likewise, suppose that $c$ was extremely large, it too can be compressed further by considering

$$ a_k (((b \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow c_1) \uparrow \uparrow c_2) \uparrow c_3 )$$

Now we generalize: take a number $X$, find the largest m such that

$$ b \uparrow^m c < X, c > 1$$

Then find the largest $c_1, c_2 ... c_{M-1} $ such that

$c_k$ is maximal given $c_1 ... c_{k-1}$ and

$$  b\uparrow ^m c \uparrow^{m-1} c_1 \uparrow^{m-2} c_2 ... \uparrow^{m-k} c_k < X \forall k \in \lbrace 1 ... m \rbrace $$

Then we can collect terms of the form

$$  b\uparrow ^m c \uparrow^{m-1} c_1 \uparrow^{m-2} c_2 ... \uparrow c_{M-1}  $$

And subtract them from $X$ repeatedly, sorting them ascending order of magnitude, summed together (collecting like terms with multiplication) to express $X$ uniquely in this extended hyperoperator notation.

Now we can consider the hereditary version of this, by re-expressing any numbers not equal to $b$ or $0$ into this form, repeatedly. Giving us hereditary hyper operator notation.

Consider now the following "Meta-Goodstein Sequence", we start with base $b=2$ and an initial value $X$. As we switch to higher bases, replace every $b$ with $b+1$ and subtract 1, re-expressing in hereditary hyper operator notation.

Claim, for all initial $X$ this goes to 0.

In the traditional goodstein example we are changing the numbers but the "form" of the numbers is steadily decreasing (using the $\omega$ argument). Now even the "form" is apparently increasing but the "form of the form" is decreasing so in third order arithmetic, one can show that this too is a sequence that goes to 0. While this problem itself requires use of functions, so must require at least second arithmetic or higher for it to be posed.

Comment: The Goodstein example should come down to the fact that the proof-theoretic ordinal of $Z_n$ is not provable well ordered in $Z_{n}$ but will be in $Z_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement "$n$th-order arithmetic is consistent" is expressible in first-order arithmetic, but not provable in $n$th-order arithmetic; and this is true for every $n$ (EDIT: and provable in $(n+1)$th order arithmetic, as per Carl's comment). We can similarly leap outside finite-order arithmetic in this way.

A more natural example: The statement "There is a structure which computes its own jump" is expressible in second-order arithmetic but not provable in $n$th-order arithmetic for any $n$; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0908.pdf.

And "Every Borel game is determined" is naturally expressible in third-order arithmetic, but not provable in any limited-order arithmetic at all; see Friedman's paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484371900180.

---

Re: the idea in your post, since every computable function can be defined in first-order arithmetic, your meta-Goodstein sentence *is* expressible in first-order arithmetic. And I don't see any reason why anything beyond $Z_2$ should be needed to prove it. In fact, I think it - and all similar ideas - still won't get you past $ATR_0$, a small fragment of second-order arithmetic.

Comment: Also $\text{Con}(Z_n)$ is provable in $Z_{n+1}$ for each $n> 0$.

Comment: That's a lot simpler than ridiculous abstract goodstein idea, thank you for this :)

Comment: How would one define the hyper operator chains in first order arithmetic? I would think that requires quantifying over sets of sets. I guess a more concrete question, can tetration be expressed in first order arithmetic?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Every computable function is definable in first order arithmetic.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas For instance, here's how to define tetration: $n=a\uparrow b$ if there is a finite sequence $s$ with $b$ elements, the last element of which is $n$, the first element of which is $a$, and such that the $(k+1)$th element is $a$ raised to the $k$th element.

Comment: Oh okay and then in general we can now define every hyper operator this, by replacing "$a$ raised to the $k^{th}$ element" with "$a$ hyperoperated by (previous hyperoperator)  with the $k^{th}$ element"

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Yes - you will also probably be interested in **effective transfinite recursion**.

Comment: @NoahSchweber how could one state that 2nd order arithmetic is consistent in first order arithmetic? It's not clear how to even say $\exists \text{2nd order arithmetic}$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Second order arithmetic is a specific recursively axiomatized formal (and, despite the name, first order) theory. The consistency of such is expressive in first order arithmetic.

Comment: (Note that this is analogous to how ZFC is a first-order theory, despite being a theory of sets.) See e.g. http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/sosoa/chapter1.pdf, starting on page 2, for a precise definition of $Z_2$.